# Angular2 - Material2 examples : MdAutoComplete

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular-material

Here is the problem,

I am actually trying the examples available there :

https://github.com/angular/material2

And I am stuck on this one :

https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/autocomplete

I use angular2 with CLI, so I have a fresh template and I try to "copy/paste" this component. But it fails with this message :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 
Can't bind to 'mdAutocomplete' since it isn't a known propery of 'input'. ("
<div class="demo-autocomplete">
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="state" [ERROR ->][mdAutocomplete]="auto">
...
...
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "mdAutocomplete"
...
```

Looks like the mdAutocomplete directive does not exist.
I follow the example step by step, is there something wrong ?

Thanks for reading/help

Comment: When you see error like angular directives/components not being recognised by the compiler, check to make sure you have added all the required dependencies/providers/imports to your module. If you forget to add them they wont be recognised.

Comment: I did, this is why I'm here. But @mxii gave the answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MdAutoComplete` isn't finished yet! https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/autocomplete

material2's changelog says:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

**2.0.0-beta.1 rebar-teacup (2016-12-23)**

- Remove `MdAutocompleteModule` that was accidentally included in beta.0
- Correct path to umd bundle in package.json (#2368) (d286e6d), closes #2366

Comment: Okay, then I'll have to make it manually, found this interesting : http://4dev.tech/2016/03/tutorial-creating-an-angular2-autocomplete/ Thanks!